# Instalação de um tema novo na loja Prestashop 1.4.3

Tags: php, template, e-commerce, compiladores

Instalei um tema usando o módulo: *export/import theme*, [**conforme mostra nesse vídeo**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXtUdFNhBME)  :  e agora estou recebendo essa mensagem no cabeçalho:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "/var/www/html/myproject/themes/food-store/header.tpl" on line 87 "<nav>{hook h="displayNav"}</nav>" unknown tag "hook"' in /var/www/html/myproject/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 431

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser esse erro?

Esta é a linha que está dando erro (87):

```
<div class="header-container">
                <header id="header">
                    <div class="banner">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                {hook h="displayBanner"}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <nav>{hook h="displayNav"}</nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="header_logo">
                                    <a href="{$base_dir}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                        <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$logo_url}" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{if $logo_image_width} width="{$logo_image_width}"{/if}{if $logo_image_height} height="{$logo_image_height}"{/if}/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                {if isset($HOOK_TOP)}{$HOOK_TOP}{/if}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
```

Nessa parte...

```
  {hook h="displayBanner"}
```

Parece que a versão que está compilando é a 3 do smarty:

```
@link http://www.smarty.net/
 * @copyright 2008 New Digital Group, Inc.
 * @author Monte Ohrt <monte at ohrt dot com> 
 * @author Uwe Tews 
 * @package Smarty
 * @version 3.0.7
```

Comment: Talvez resolve, `{' '|implode:$body_classes}`

Comment: esse primeiro erro resolveu!

Comment: Agora o erro mudou de linha...:( -> vou editar a pergunta...

Comment: Tem noção do que esse `hook` faz? ele gera algum style? qual versao do smarty é?

Comment: Acredito que seja a versão 2.0. Esse hook deve ser como um include, acho.

Comment: No smarty 2 vc tem não pode ter uma tag `<style>` no template precisa escapar com `{style} css {/style}`, tente envolver o `{hook}` com o `{style}`

Comment: Tentei assim: `{style}{hook h="displayBanner"}{/style}`, e não deu certo.

Comment: O themes novos, tal como módulos, normalmente não dão suporte a uma versão tão antiga como 1.4.. Ao menos deveria estar na 1.5. O recomendado é estar sempre na versão mais recente. Se puder, migre para a versão atual 1.6.1.3

Comment: Pois é então, o [tema comprado](http://addons.prestashop.com/pt/food-drinks/19550-foodstore-responsive.html) não foi feito para versões inferiores, o problema é que não queremos atualizar para a versão nova, pois teríamos que treinar o pessoal a usar a nova plataforma do admin, está fora de cogitação. Eu até fiz um teste instalando o tema em uma versão recente 1.6.1.2 e ele aplicou o tema sem dar nenhum erro, mas eu tenho que adaptá-lo para uma versão mais antiga, então estou fazendo isso por etapas...